# What is the device interface GUID of USB4 host routers under Windows?

Tags: usb

Mircosoft seems to offer now USB4 drivers for Windows 11:
[image: USB4 device manager]

To make my application [UsbTreeView](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) show these I need to know the device interface GUID of "USB4(TM) Host Router (Microsoft)", the equivalent to GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER of USB1..3 host controllers.
I've checked the latest Windows Driver Kit for it, but no USB4 there yet...

As far as I know it isn't shown anywhere in Windows, so here is my command-line-tool "ListDevices" which does:
https://www.uwe-sieber.de/files/ListDevices.zip

So if you have a working USB4 controller then please unzip the containing folder and start the ListDevices2txt.cmd which excutes the console tool ListDevices.exe and redirects its output to a text file and opens it in the default text editor application.
Search for "Host Router" in this text file to find the right device. The interface GUID is part of the Device Path which is shown in the first line for each device.

Thanks,
Uwe Sieber

Comment: StackOverflow might not be the best place.  I'd try https://community.osr.com/ and the libusb mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the requested data as response to the same request on my homepage. So the answer to the question is:
A "USB4(TM) Host Router (Microsoft)" does not have a device interface assigned, so there is no such GUID, so it cannot be enumerated by means of SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces with the DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE.

In case it is of interest, here ListDevice.exe's output for a USB4 Host Router and its Root Router:

```
    ===============================================================
Device ID                         = PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&SUBSYS_162F1022&REV_00&USB4_MS_CM\4&3B47FC12&0&0643
DevInst                           = 128
DevInst Parent                    = 339 (PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_14B9&SUBSYS_22F117AA&REV_10\3&2411E6FE&1&43)
DevInst Child                     = 13, 258
Status                            = 0x180000A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem                           = 0 (-)
SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS               = PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&REV_00 PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F PCI\VEN_1022&CC_0C0340 PCI\VEN_1022&CC_0C03 PCI\VEN_1022 PCI\CC_0C0340&DT_0 PCI\CC_0C0340 PCI\CC_0C03&DT_0 PCI\CC_0C03
SPDRP_HARDWAREID                  = PCI\USB4_MS_CM PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&SUBSYS_162F1022&REV_00 PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&SUBSYS_162F1022 PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&CC_0C0340 PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&CC_0C03
SPDRP_DEVICEDESC                  = USB4(TM) Host Router (Microsoft)
SPDRP_SERVICE                     = Usb4HostRouter
SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME             = PCI
SPDRP_BUSTYPEGUID                 = {C8EBDFB0-B510-11D0-80E5-00A0C92542E3} (GUID_BUS_TYPE_PCI)
SPDRP_LEGACYBUSTYPE               = PCIBus
SPDRP_BUSNUMBER                   = 100
SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION        = PCI bus 100, device 0, function 6
SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS              = PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0803)#PCI(0006) ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(GP19)#ACPI(NHI1)
SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME = \Device\NTPNP_PCI0035
SPDRP_CAPABILITIES                = 0x00 (-)
SPDRP_CLASS                       = USB
SPDRP_CLASSGUID                   = {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
SPDRP_DRIVER                      = {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0006
SPDRP_MFG                         = Generic USB4 Host Router
SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS                 = 0x00 (-)
SPDRP_ADDRESS                     = 0x06 (6)
SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY              = 1 (CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL)
SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_HW_DEFAULT   = 1 (CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL)
SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE               = 0 (CM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED)
SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA           = MostRecentPowerState=D3

===============================================================
Device Path 0                     = \\?\USB4#ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER&VID_1022&PID_162F#5&a169261&0&0#{d830231d-81ce-409b-84fe-ece5c24a479f}
Device Path 1                     = \\?\USB4#ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER&VID_1022&PID_162F#5&a169261&0&0#{3b6d80c9-039c-44ca-ba0e-33ba62a5cfb8}
Device ID                         = USB4\ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER&VID_1022&PID_162F\5&A169261&0&0
DevInst                           = 258
DevInst Parent                    = 128 (PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_162F&SUBSYS_162F1022&REV_00&USB4_MS_CM\4&3B47FC12&0&0643)
Status                            = 0x180000A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem                           = 0 (-)
SPDRP_COMPATIBLEIDS               = USB4\ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER USB4\DEVICE_ROUTER
SPDRP_HARDWAREID                  = USB4\ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER&VID_1022&PID_162F&REV_0000 USB4\ROOT_DEVICE_ROUTER&VID_1022&PID_162F
SPDRP_DEVICEDESC                  = USB4 Root Router
SPDRP_SERVICE                     = Usb4DeviceRouter
SPDRP_ENUMERATOR_NAME             = USB4
SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME = \Device\00000094
SPDRP_CAPABILITIES                = 0x00 (-)
SPDRP_CLASS                       = USB
SPDRP_CLASSGUID                   = {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
SPDRP_DRIVER                      = {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0019
SPDRP_MFG                         = Generic USB4 Device Router
SPDRP_CONFIGFLAGS                 = 0x00 (-)
SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY              = 1 (CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL)
SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY_HW_DEFAULT   = 1 (CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_NO_REMOVAL)
SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE               = 0 (CM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED)
SPDRP_DEVICE_POWER_DATA           = MostRecentPowerState=D3
```